# How to set the container to a draggable element's handle in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, handle, containment

I have an absolute div inside of another absolute positioned div.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="drag">
        <div id="handle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example, assume the container is 1000px x 1000px, the "drag" element is 100px x 100px and the "handle" element is 10px x 10px inside of the drag element at x = 30px and y = 30px.

The following code will set the drag element to stay within the container element:

```
$('#drag').draggable({ handle: '#handle', containment: '#container' });
```

I would like for the drag element to extend beyond the container, but stop dragging at the handle borders. How can I do this without using set coordinates?